# Error trying to generate a jupyter notebook config file

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to change some settings in the jupyter notebook interface --- e.g., display line numbers, display right margin guide --- so that they are always displayed.

Since my `~/.jupyter/` dir contains only one file (`migrated`) and no `/nbconfig/` dir or `notebook.json` file, I ran `jupyter notebook --generate-config` at the prompt to create a new config file. This produced a couple errors related to sqlite3 and pysqlite2.

I checked my installed packages and I do have sqlite 3.26.0 installed, though not pysqlite2.

From the error message I'm not sure if the second error related to pysqlite2 is raised only b/c sqlite3 wasn't found, or if I need to install pysqlite2. If it's required for such a basic operation as creating a config file I'm wondering why it wouldn't be part of the Anaconda full install I did a few weeks ago.

I'm on Windows 10 running Anaconda 2018.12, anaconda-client 1.7.2, jupyter notebook server 5.7.4-f6790e4 on Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)], IPython 7.2.0.

Here's the commands and full output in case seeing other installed packages is helpful:

`k@DESKTOP-VAQRJL8 MINGW64 ~ (master)`
`$` **`jupyter notebook --generate-config`**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\karls\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 10, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "C:\Users\karls\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\karls\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karls\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\karls\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 86, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "C:\Users\karls\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

`k@DESKTOP-VAQRJL8 MINGW64 ~ (master)`
`$` **`conda list`**

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\karls\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
anaconda                  2018.12                  py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.6                    py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py37_0
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0
astroid                   2.1.0                    py37_0
astropy                   3.1              py37he774522_0
atomicwrites              1.2.1                    py37_0
attrs                     18.2.0           py37h28b3542_0
babel                     2.6.0                    py37_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
backports                 1.0                      py37_1
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2
bcrypt                    3.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
beautifulsoup4            4.6.3                    py37_0
bitarray                  0.8.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blaze                     0.11.3                   py37_0
bleach                    3.0.2                    py37_0
blosc                     1.14.4               he51fdeb_0
bokeh                     1.0.2                    py37_0
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h452e1ab_1
bzip2                     1.0.6                hfa6e2cd_5
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0
certifi                   2018.11.29               py37_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py37h74b6da3_1
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1
click                     7.0                      py37_0
cloudpickle               0.6.1                    py37_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
comtypes                  1.1.7                    py37_0
conda                     4.6.3                    py37_0
conda-build               3.17.6                   py37_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-verify              3.1.1                    py37_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         3
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py37_0
cryptography              2.4.2            py37h7a1dbc1_0
curl                      7.63.0            h2a8f88b_1000
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cython                    0.29.2           py37ha925a31_0
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py37hfa6e2cd_1
dask                      1.0.0                    py37_0
dask-core                 1.0.0                    py37_0
datashape                 0.5.4                    py37_1
decorator                 4.3.0                    py37_0
defusedxml                0.5.0                    py37_1
distributed               1.25.1                   py37_0
dnspython                 1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.14                     py37_0
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py37_2
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0
faker                     0.8.13                   pypi_0    pypi
fastcache                 1.0.2            py37hfa6e2cd_2
filelock                  3.0.10                   py37_0
flask                     0.12.4                   pypi_0    pypi
flask-bcrypt              0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
flask-cors                3.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
flask-jwt-extended        3.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
flask-login               0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
future                    0.17.1                   py37_0
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    1.3.7            py37he774522_1
glob2                     0.6                      py37_1
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37hfa6e2cd_0
h5py                      2.8.0            py37h3bdd7fb_2
hdf5                      1.10.2               hac2f561_1
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py37_2
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
imageio                   2.4.1                    py37_0
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0
importlib_metadata        0.6                      py37_0
intel-openmp              2019.1                      144
ipykernel                 5.1.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.2.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    py37_0
isort                     4.3.4                    py37_0
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0
jdcal                     1.4                      py37_0
jedi                      0.13.2                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10                     py37_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter-client            5.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py37_0
jupyterlab                0.35.3                   py37_0
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                    py37_0
keyring                   17.0.0                   py37_0
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py37h6538335_0
krb5                      1.16.1               hc04afaa_7
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py37hfa6e2cd_2
libarchive                3.3.3                h0643e63_5
libcurl                   7.63.0            h2a8f88b_1000
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libpng                    1.6.35               h2a8f88b_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libssh2                   1.8.0                h7a1dbc1_4
libtiff                   4.0.9                h36446d0_2
libxml2                   2.9.8                hadb2253_1
libxslt                   1.1.32               hf6f1972_0
llvmlite                  0.26.0           py37ha925a31_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
lxml                      4.2.5            py37hef2cd61_0
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h2fa13f4_0
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.1.0            py37he774522_0
matplotlib                3.0.2            py37hc8f65d3_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
menuinst                  1.4.14           py37hfa6e2cd_0
mistune                   0.8.4            py37he774522_0
mkl                       2019.1                      144
mkl-service               1.1.2            py37hb782905_5
mkl_fft                   1.0.6            py37h6288b17_0
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h343c172_0
more-itertools            4.3.0                    py37_0
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py37he980bc4_1
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0
nbconvert                 5.4.0                    py37_1
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
networkx                  2.2                      py37_1
nltk                      3.4                      py37_1
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2
notebook                  5.7.4                    py37_0
numba                     0.41.0           py37hf9181ef_0
numexpr                   2.6.8            py37hdce8814_0
numpy                     1.15.4           py37h19fb1c0_0
numpy-base                1.15.4           py37hc3f5095_0
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py37_0
objgraph                  3.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
odo                       0.5.1                    py37_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openpyxl                  2.5.12                   py37_0
openssl                   1.1.1a               he774522_0
packaging                 18.0                     py37_0
pandas                    0.23.4           py37h830ac7b_0
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hb2460c7_1
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
parso                     0.3.1                    py37_0
partd                     0.3.9                    py37_0
path.py                   11.5.0                   py37_0
pathlib2                  2.3.3                    py37_0
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pillow                    5.3.0            py37hdc69c19_0
pip                       18.1                     py37_0
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py37_1
pluggy                    0.8.0                    py37_0
ply                       3.11                     py37_0
prometheus_client         0.5.0                    py37_0
prompt-toolkit            2.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.4.8            py37he774522_0
py                        1.7.0                    py37_0
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37hfa6e2cd_9
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py37h7a1dbc1_0
pyflakes                  2.0.0                    py37_0
pygments                  2.3.1                    py37_0
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pylint                    2.2.2                    py37_0
pymongo                   3.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyodbc                    4.0.25           py37ha925a31_0
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.3.0                    py37_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py37_0
pytables                  3.4.4            py37he6f6034_0
pytest                    4.0.2                    py37_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.2.0                    py37_0
pytest-flask              0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pytest-openfiles          0.3.1                    py37_0
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0
python                    3.7.1                h8c8aaf0_6
python-dateutil           2.7.5                    py37_0
python-graphviz           0.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
python-libarchive-c       2.8                      py37_6
pytz                      2018.7                   py37_0
pywavelets                1.0.1            py37h8c2d366_0
pywin32                   223              py37hfa6e2cd_1
pywinpty                  0.5.5                 py37_1000
pyyaml                    3.13             py37hfa6e2cd_0
pyzmq                     17.1.2                   pypi_0    pypi
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0  [vc14]
qtawesome                 0.5.3                    py37_0
qtconsole                 4.4.3                    py37_0
qtpy                      1.5.2                    py37_0
requests                  2.21.0                   py37_0
rope                      0.11.0                   py37_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37hfa6e2cd_0
scikit-image              0.14.1           py37ha925a31_0
scikit-learn              0.20.1           py37h343c172_0
scipy                     1.1.0            py37h29ff71c_2
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                40.6.3                   py37_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py37_0
sortedcollections         1.0.1                    py37_0
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0
sphinx                    1.8.2                    py37_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py37_1
spyder                    3.3.2                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            0.3.0                    py37_0
sqlalchemy                1.2.15           py37he774522_0
sqlite                    3.26.0               he774522_0
statsmodels               0.9.0            py37h452e1ab_0
sympy                     1.3                      py37_0
tblib                     1.3.2                    py37_0
terminado                 0.8.1                    py37_1
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0
text-unidecode            1.2                      pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
toolz                     0.9.0                    py37_0
tornado                   5.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0
tqdm                      4.28.1           py37h28b3542_0
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0
urllib3                   1.24.1                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py37_0
wheel                     0.32.3                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.0.1                    py37_1
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.10.11          py37hfa6e2cd_2
xdot                      1.0                      pypi_0    pypi
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xlsxwriter                1.1.2                    py37_0
xlwings                   0.15.1                   py37_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zeromq                    4.2.5                he025d50_1
zict                      0.1.3                    py37_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```